# Site template works only on top of a site collection

Tags: 2010, site-collection, site-template, sub-site

When trying to create subsite from a given template anywhere but the top of the site collection, this error occurs:

```
    Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: 
An unexpected error has occurred. -{group and site Ids here} - Inner Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException: Value does not fall within the expected range.    
Server stack trace: at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(SPPrincipal principalToFind)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection_SubsetProxy.GetAssignmentByPrincipal__Inner(SPPrincipal_SubsetProxy principalToFind)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection_SubsetProxy.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(SPPrincipal_SubsetProxy principalToFind)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection_SubsetProxy.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(SPPrincipal_SubsetProxy principalToFind)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection.GetAssignmentByPrincipal__Inner(SPPrincipal principalToFind)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(SPPrincipal principalToFind)     at Roche.TP.PDCore.Code.Commands.SitePagesRightsCommand.AssignPersonalViewsEditPermission(SPWeb web, SPList sitePages, Int32 groupId)     at Roche.TP.PDCore.Code.Commands.SitePagesRightsCommand.Execute(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Roche.TP.SandboxCommon.Infrastructure.Commands.BaseCommandCollection.Execute(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Roche.TP.PDCore.Features.Web_PDCore.Web_PDCoreEventReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeFeatureCallOutWrapper.ExecuteInternal(Object userCodeObject, SPUserCodeRemoteExecutionContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeRemoteExecutionWrapper.Execute(SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.ExecuteWrapper(SPUserCodeWrapper wrapper, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)    Exception rethrown at [1]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.CodeToExecuteWrapper.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)
```

As i described, given template works only of top of a site collection, any other template (this is a custom one) works, even custom ones. Any ideas?

Edit:

This error is not reproducible, it happens only on 1 site collection with 1 particular template. It fails on activating one of the features, but when I created blank subsite and activated feature it failed on manually, it activated without any problems.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is.

Comment: @DerekGusoff I know, "value does not fall within the expected range". The problem is: which value, or how can I determine it, since I cannot attach process to the visual studio for example to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "fixed it" by creating site from this template at the top of a site collection, and then saving it as a new template. Somehow, the new one works even in problematic subsites. If anyone will have an idea why it works like that, I'll be grateful.